# Add a button and check-boxes dynamically to my list view?

Tags: android

I have a list view showing all the names of the contacts in the phone.
I want, on the click of a button, for check boxes to appear in front of each row in the list view. Tap any single item of a list view once, and a delete button should appear in front of that respective row.

Here is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView android:layout_height="350dp" android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginTop="35dp">

    </ListView>

    <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_height="35dp" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="70dp" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></Button>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Favourites" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:gravity="center"></TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I get my text view from this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.96" android:layout_height="73dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_name"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="218dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the CheckBoxes to your xml-File and make them invisible.
Than add a code snippet in your listViewAdapter's `getView` to make the CheckBox Visible or invisible if for example a boolean Variable is false or true.
Now if you change these Variable just call `notifyDataSetChanged();` on your Filter Adapter,

Comment: 11-07 13:21:11.670: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(623): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.a3.Activities/com.a3.Activities.Favourites}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
.......Adding checkbox and setting its visibility to gone showing the above error